# Can new tires cause transmission failure

Tags: honda, tires, transmission, awd, passport

Question about transmission failure.

2019 Honda Passport AWD Elite:
9-26-23 put on 4 new tires “265/45R-20XL 108V ION EVO all season SUV”. Had 65,198 miles at the time. Tire Center said they were used on Teslas & other electric vehicles. Said it would give me a smooth ride. I did say my vehicle probably doesn’t weigh as much as a Tesla & mine is AWD would that make a difference?
Assured me these would give me the smoothest ride.
300 miles later I got a warning “transmission failure” at driving speed of 65. I slowed down to exit highway, then when I accelerated to continue the transmission struggled. Same thing when accelerating from a complete stop. Had to get towed.
Reflecting back I did notice that sometimes car acceleration was sluggish. Sometimes shifting gears car would jerk a little. And felt like car was dragging when driving.
I Wonder if dealer put on all brand new tires with same tread wear.
My Honda dealer said I’m the first to bring in a 2019 passport with transmission damage. Drove about 300 miles on new tires.
Car driven on city and highway roads only. No hauling or towing. No snow driving. One City driver.
Can new tires be the cause?

I told Tire Center after a week of driving I wanted to exchange the tires because the ride was not smooth. Was to go back later this week to exchange. Have 60 days satisfaction warranty.

Can new tires be the cause?

Also I may be wrong but I feel like the car doesn’t sit as high as it used too.

Comment: I read an article in the Wall Street Journal (but I can't find it again in their search) about how the tires for Teslas and other EVs are fundamentally different in terms of their stiffness, etc. So conceivably, it could.

Comment: @MarkStewart What mechanism would cause such damage? I struggle to imagine such a feedback, especially in such a short distance.

Comment: It does seem unlikely to cause such havoc in a short period of time... Unfortunately, I don't remember the details from the article, but it did sound it could cause trouble.

Comment: I agree, extremely unlikely in 300 miles.  Unfortunate happenstance.  Is the outer diameter of the tire significantly different than the OE tire? That would make your gearing taller and your acceleration less peppy. But the others sound like a growing transmission problem.  60k miles is a very unusual time for that to happen, though.  Usually it fails very soon after manufacture due to factory defect, or lasts 120k+++.

Comment: @MarkStewart I know for a fact that Teslas will just smoke a standard tire. We had to start turning down our Tesla cutomers, because they came back in 10K miles with bald tires that are supposed to last 65K. SOOOO, yes, they get different tires from factory, but they are not that much better. They really only last about 20K miles, and they cost the same.